# Why does the curve I've plotted show exclusions?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the following function.

[image]

As we can see, it is function of theta so that I used `Plot[%, {theta, 1, 10}]`. However, the plot shows some disconnected areas. I'm wondering why these disconnected areas or points arise.

```
-((3 θ)/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[9 θ^2 + 2/3 θ (-1 + 18 θ) + (θ^2 (-23 - 252 θ + 324 θ^2))/(3 (73 θ^3 - 702 θ^4 + 6804 θ^5 - 5832 θ^6 + 54 Sqrt[6]Sqrt[θ^6 + 17 θ^7 + 306 θ^8 - 324 θ^9])^(1/3)) + 1/3 (73 θ^3 - 702 θ^4 + 6804 θ^5 - 5832 θ^6 + 54 Sqrt[6]Sqrt[θ^6 + 17 θ^7 + 306 θ^8 - 324 θ^9])^(1/3)] + 1/2 √(18 θ^2 + 4/3 θ (-1 + 18 θ) - (θ^2 (-23 - 252 θ + 324 θ^2))/(3 (73 θ^3 - 702 θ^4 + 6804 θ^5 - 5832 θ^6 + 54 Sqrt[6]Sqrt[θ^6 + 17 θ^7 + 306 θ^8 - 324 θ^9])^(1/3)) - 1/3 (73 θ^3 - 702 θ^4 + 6804 θ^5 -5832 θ^6 + 54 Sqrt[6]Sqrt[θ^6 + 17 θ^7 + 306 θ^8 - 324 θ^9])^(1/3) - (-96 θ^2 - 216 θ^3 - 24 θ^2 (-1 + 18 θ))/(4 Sqrt[9 θ^2 + 2/3 θ (-1 + 18 θ) + (θ^2 (-23 - 252 θ + 324 θ^2))/(3 (73 θ^3 - 702 θ^4 + 6804 θ^5 - 5832 θ^6 + 54 Sqrt[6]Sqrt[θ^6 + 17 θ^7 + 306 θ^8 - 324 θ^9])^(1/3)) + 1/3 (73 θ^3 - 702 θ^4 + 6804 θ^5 - 5832 θ^6 + 54 Sqrt[6]Sqrt[θ^6 + 17 θ^7 + 306 θ^8 - 324 θ^9])^(1/3)]))

Plot[%, {θ, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Plot just that denominator and look at its zeros.

Comment: Always post code (Raw InputForm) that can be copied and pasted into a notebook rather than pictures of code.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook.

Comment: For formatting posts, you may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that due to numerical roundoff errors, the imaginary part of the expression does not calculate to an exact zero, but merely a very small number.  Try plotting the real part and the imaginary part separately.  The imaginary part is very small and noisy, from which we can conclude that it is due to roundoff errors.

[image]

The simple workaround is to plot the real part only.

Comment: Does it means that the equation with respect to theta in my question includes a complex number?

Comment: @JensenKang `Sqrt` is applied to negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Plot[%, {θ, 1, 10},WorkingPrecision->20]
```

[image]